# Vlookup with a condition returns #N/A for matched data

Tags: excel, excel-2007, vlookup

I am trying to create a vlookup with a condition, [link](http://www.get-digital-help.com/2012/10/31/use-multiple-conditions-in-vlookup/). All combinations are unique, so `Chicken - Sausage` will only appear once. I have checked my formula and this is what happens;

1. Formula checks `column A` for any cells that match `Chicken`.
2. Result is `FALSE/FALSE/TRUE/TRUE/FALSE/TRUE/...`
3. Formula filters out all the falses and returns the data of the trues.
4. Retrieved data is all `#N/A`
5. Result = #N/A

**But why is all the retrieved data `#N/A`? It should list `Chicken x x x x Sausage/....` Other columns are of no use or interest in this question.**

`=VLOOKUP("Sausage";IF(Extra!$A$2:$A$4032="Chicken";Extra!$A$2:$H$4032;"");7;0)`

**Data Sample**

```
Extra
Meat     x x x x x Sausage
Chicken  x x x x x Sausage 
Turkey   x x x x x Sausage
Chicken  x x x x x Breast
Chicken  x x x x x Wings
```

---

**Jerry:**

Hi Jerry, I want to look for `Sausage` in Sheet `Extra`. With a normal VLOOKUP it will only show the first result, even if you 3 results (Chicken Sausage, Meat Sausage, Turkey Sausage). So I added an extra condition, `Chicken`. Following the link I provided I'm looking for `Sausage (A)` in Sheet `Extra` and it's linked to `Chicken (South-America)`.

This should result in:

```
=VLOOKUP("A",{"", "", "", "", "";"", "", "", "", "";"", "", "", "", "";"", "", "", "", "";"A", "South America", "The New Firm", "Tory", "Byrnes";"", "", "", "", "";"", "", "", "", "";"", "", "", "", "";"", "", "", "", "";"F", "South America", "Trans United Airways", "Ervin", "Hennessey"},3,FALSE)
```

But all I get is:

```
=VLOOKUP("Sausage",{"", "", "", "", "";"", "", "", "", "";"", "", "", "", "";"", "", "", "", "";"#N/A", "#N/A", "#N/A", "#N/A", "#N/A";"", "", "", "", "";"", "", "", "", "";"", "", "", "", "";"", "", "", "", "";"#N/A", "#N/A", "#N/A", "#N/A", "#N/A"},7,FALSE)
```

Comment: Um.. what is your question exactly?

Comment: My question is; Why is it returning #N/A and not Chicken x x x x x Sausage/Chicken x x x x x Breast ... As in the link provided.

Comment: In the link I provided they use different data, but the rest should be the same. Also edited my post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`VLOOKUP` is looking for `Sausage` in the array returned by the `IF` function. This array has all the rows in `A2:H4032` that has `Chicken` in the column `A`.

Since `Sausage` is never equal to `Chicken`, you never will get a result.

`VLOOKUP` looks for the first parameter `Sausage` in the **first** column of the array.

**Insertion from comment:**

In the link, the condition (region) South-America is used in the condition, the item A is used for the vlookup to get back a company name (3 things). You are using Chicken for the condition, Sausage for the vlookup to get back what? Additionally, when you looking up something in vlookup, the something has to be in the first column of the array. In the example the region was in the first column!

I'm not sure what you're trying to get, but either you move some columns around to make 'Sausage' in column A, or change the returned array from `IF` so the the first column contains 'Sausage'.

Comment: Jerry, added my comment to my first post to make it clearer.

Comment: @t.thielemans In the link, the condition (region) `South-America` is used in the condition, the item `A` is used for the vlookup to get back a company name (3 things). You are using Chicken for the condition, Sausage for the vlookup to get back what? Additionally, when you looking up something in vlookup, the something has to be in the first column of the array. In the example the region was in the first column!

Comment: What a miserable fail -.- I changed my range from A to F: `F(Extra!$A$2:$A$4032="Chicken";Extra!$A$2:$H$4032;"")` to `F(Extra!$A$2:$A$4032="Chicken";Extra!$F$2:$H$4032;"")` and now it works ... VLOOKUP lesson 1 LOL! If you add that to your answer I can accept it :)

Comment: @t.thielemans Okay, this will no more give you errors, though I guess that's okay for the time being ^^; Added that bit to my answer.

Comment: Can't believe I failed that hard ...

Comment: @t.thielemans Hey, that's okay, don't sweat it :) As long as it was a genuine question ^^ And everyone can make mistakes, and you updated your question with the relevant information, that's good ^^